# Using mimetools.Message in urllib2.urlopen

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm using `urllib2.urlopen()`:

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print resp.info()

print resp.info()['set-cookie']

Date: Sat, 14 May 2011 01:24:12 GMT

Expires: -1

Cache-Control: private, max-age=0

Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=5ec78624283cc050:FF=0:TM=1305336252:LM=1305336252:S=eRXgUUuzhQbRmZxk; expires=Mon, 13-May-2013 01:24:12 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com

Set-Cookie: NID=46=GxyZVeWbT9dn0sLa9waPGSusm1hFqGf46SPqewahg0bzbYIQX0oHff0bzJ33E2yO89npEsYkqSoX0HLSqHbCxj5tCK2E931PfEJbqDMB6lTDk4ngVAiiyObWmbHgRUC9; expires=Sun, 13-Nov-2011 01:24:12 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly

Server: gws

X-XSS-Protection: 1; mod


PREF=ID=5ec78624283cc050:FF=0:TM=1305336252:LM=1305336252:S=eRXgUUuzhQbRmZxk; expires=Mon, 13-May-2013 01:24:12 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com, NID=46=GxyZVeWbT9dn0sLa9waPGSusm1hFqGf46SPqewahg0bzbYIQX0oHff0bzJ33E2yO89npEsYkqSoX0HLSqHbCxj5tCK2E931PfEJbqDMB6lTDk4ngVAiiyObWmbHgRUC9; expires=Sun, 13-Nov-2011 01:24:12 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
```

As you can see in the headers received in the response, there are TWO statements of 'set-cookie', HOWEVER in the `resp.info()` object I receive it has grouped both cookie statements together and separates them by a ',' (comma)

This is troublesome to separate the cookies by this delimiter since there are commas inside the cookie information i'm try to separate with this comma delimiter

Is there an easy way to call upon each cookie string individually with this mimetools.message object? (`resp.info()`)

else-> I'll just have to parse the headers manually without this not so helpful mimetools.message/dictionary object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`getheaders()`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPResponse.getheaders) to get a `list` of the cookies:

```
>>> msg = resp.info()
>>> msg.getheaders('Set-Cookie')
['PREF=ID=5975a5ee255f0949:FF=0:TM=1305336283:LM=1305336283:S=1vkES6eF4Yxd-_oM; expires=Mon, 13-May-2013 01:24:43 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com.au', 'NID=46=lQVFZg6yKUsoWT529Hqp5gA8B_CKYd2epPIbANmw_J0UzeMt2BhuMF-gtmGsRhenUTeajKz2zILXd9xWpHWT8ZGvDcmNdkzaGX-L_-sKyY1w4e2l3DKd80JzSkt2Vp-H; expires=Sun, 13-Nov-2011 01:24:43 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com.au; HttpOnly']
```

In this case, you get a `list` of two `string`s.

Then you can iterate over that `list` and grab whichever cookie you like. [`str.startswith()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) is your friend:

```
>>> cookies = msg.getheaders('Set-Cookie')
>>> for cookie in cookies:
...     if cookie.startswith('PREF='):
...             print 'Got PREF: ', cookie
...     else:
...             print 'Got another: ', cookie
... 
Got PREF:  PREF=ID=5975a5ee255f0949:FF=0:TM=1305336283:LM=1305336283:S=1vkES6eF4Yxd-_oM; expires=Mon, 13-May-2013 01:24:43 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com.au
Got another:  NID=46=lQVFZg6yKUsoWT529Hqp5gA8B_CKYd2epPIbANmw_J0UzeMt2BhuMF-gtmGsRhenUTeajKz2zILXd9xWpHWT8ZGvDcmNdkzaGX-L_-sKyY1w4e2l3DKd80JzSkt2Vp-H; expires=Sun, 13-Nov-2011 01:24:43 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com.au; HttpOnly
```

### How a newbie can find the documentation in Python

```
% python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jan 29 2011, 13:30:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com')
>>> resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> help(resp.info())
```

Comment: excellent! getheaders() method was just what I was looking for! Where is the documentation?

Comment: He has linked the documentation. It is from httplib, as urllib2 returns a HTTPResponse object.

Comment: @MistahX: Happy to help. I've updated my answer with a link to the online documentation as well as illustrating how I found it.

Comment: @MistahX: By the way, "just what I was looking for!" is best expressed as a green tick next to the most helpful answer, as per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: this is now (once you do `help(resp.info())`) `.get_content_type|maintype|subtype()`